# What does the probabilistic approach to PDE give us that we can't obtain otherwise?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, big-picture

My apologies for the naive question. As someone from a PDE background, I am just wondering what core things can be said using probabilistic methods about certain PDE problems that couldn't be said without probability. Perhaps my question can be summarised as: **why should someone working in PDEs learn some stochastic analysis**?

As a concrete example, given an elliptic operator in non-divergence form $$\mathcal L_t=a^{ij}(t,x)\partial_{ij}+b^i(t,x)\partial_i$$ my understanding is that given regularity on the coefficients, the solution to the Cauchy problem $\partial_tu+\mathcal L_tu=0$ with sufficiently regular initial data $u(0,\cdot)=u_0(\cdot)$ can be written as the integral of some functional on Wiener space $$u(t,x)=\mathbb E^x[u_0(X_t)],$$ where $X_t$ is the Markov process with generator $\mathcal L_t$. Disregarding the fact that this is only valid for second order operators, does this Markov process method allow to consider coefficients $a^{ij}, b^i$ beyond what's known with non-probabilistic methods?

Comment: Consider one of the most basic example : the heat equation. [See for example the historical paper by the celebrated Doob (father of martingales) (www.ams.org/journals/tran/1955-080-01/S0002-9947-1955-0079376-0/S0002-9947-1955-0079376-0.pdf)], in the simplistic case of a rectangular boundary ; if I take the prosaic point of view of simulation : working with random "particles" issued from a same point will permit you to estimate the temperature at that point without needing a global solution.

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you for the comment! The link you provided doesn't seem to work; would you mind telling me the name of the paper?

Comment: last article in (http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1955-080-01/)

Comment: The reason to learn stochastic analysis or probability is that there are a ton of interesting problems at the intersection of PDE and probability. For example, stochastic games and the p-Laplacian (https://math.berkeley.edu/~evans/brezis.pdf), the Kardar–Parisi–Zhang equation in statistical physics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kardar%E2%80%93Parisi%E2%80%93Zhang_equation), and stochastic homogenization, which has applications in materials science, just to name a few.